# Single Loss for Multiple Outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss

I would like to create a neural network in Keras/Tensorflow which has multiple outputs. I would like to create a SINGLE loss function which takes all outputs into account and computes the loss accordingly. I need to do this because the outputs are related to each other. How can I achieve this? I read about concatenating all outputs to a single dense layer and then calculating the loss for this layer. Is there a more convenient way to achieve a single loss for multiple outputs yet?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
def my_custom_loss(y_true_0, ..., y_true_n, y_pred_0, ..., y_pred_n):
   return something
```

`y_true_0, ..., y_true_n` and `y_pred_0, ..., y_pred_n`

should be the true / predicted outputs of n output (dense) layers.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement loss functions based on the nature of your variables. Some standard ones are given below:

If they're just numbers (and not probabilities):
MSE loss

```
def my_custom_loss(y_true_0, ..., y_true_n, y_pred_0, ..., y_true_n):
   y_true = tf.stack([y_true_0,...y_true_n], axis=0)
   y_pred = tf.stack([y_pred_0,...y_pred_n], axis=0)
   something = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
   return something
```

**OR** Absolute difference loss

```
def my_custom_loss(y_true_0, ..., y_true_n, y_pred_0, ..., y_true_n):
   y_true = tf.stack([y_true_0,...y_true_n], axis=0)
   y_pred = tf.stack([y_pred_0,...y_pred_n], axis=0)
   something = tf.losses.absolute_difference(y_true, y_pred)
   return something
```

If they're one hot vectors (valid probabilities):

```
def my_custom_loss(y_true_0, ..., y_true_n, y_pred_0, ..., y_true_n):
   y_true = tf.stack([y_true_0,...y_true_n], axis=0)
   y_pred = tf.stack([y_pred_0,...y_pred_n], axis=0)
   something = tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred))
   return something
```

If they're zeros and ones (not valid probabilities):

```
def my_custom_loss(y_true_0, ..., y_true_n, y_pred_0, ..., y_true_n):
   y_true = tf.stack([y_true_0,...y_true_n], axis=0)
   y_pred = tf.stack([y_pred_0,...y_pred_n], axis=0)
   something = tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), from_logits=True)
   return something
```

It is not just limited to these. You can create your own loss function provided it is differentiable.

Comment: thanks but thats not what i was looking for. the question is how can I access multiple outputs in a single loss function. --> where do i get all the y_true_0, ..., y_true_n / y_pred_0, ..., y_pred_n from

Comment: Doesn't "I would like to create a SINGLE loss function which takes all outputs into account and computes the loss accordingly." mean this?

Comment: maybe I should clarify: I have a multi output network (>1 output layers). is there a way to collect all output layers logits in a single loss function

Comment: ok, now I'm confused, do you need the loss function or all the outputs?

Comment: sorry for confusion. i need all the outputs as inputs to a single function. usually each output layer of a network has its own loss function.